# How to use relative links in Bot Framework Webchat messages?

Tags: reactjs, botframework, web-chat

I have a bot that returns relative links to other pages in some of the plain text messages but they don't open.
If I give the full URL it opens in a new window which isn't ideal.

```js
await context.sendActivity({ 
        type: ActivityTypes.Message, 
        text: 'To know more about our team please click [here](/about/team)'
});
```

"To know more about our website please click here"

where **here** is the link as in the example below

Example

```html
 <a href="/about/team">here</a>
```

BotFramework-WebChat v4.13.0

botbuilder-js v4.13.1

The site with the bot is built with react and react-router.

Comment: Can you provide more of the relevant code? Where does that snippet live? How is it being called - in an adaptive card, plain text in an activity, something else? Which version of Web Chat are you using?

Comment: @StevenKanberg - I've updated the question with the details and sample.